# RailsでPostgreSQLのArray型で、配列が空のものを取得する方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

RailsでPostgreSQLのArray型を使った時に、配列が空のもののみを取得するにはどうすればいいでしょうか。

例えば、次のコードのようにpreload_article_idsが配列型(Integer)だとして、次のようなコードを書けば取得できるのかなと思いました。

```
Article.where("array_length(preload_article_ids, 1) = 0")
```

しかし、実際には取得することが出来ませんでした。どうすれば空の場合のみ取得できるか、ご教授頂けませんでしょうか。よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array_length('{}'::int[], 1)
```

は0ではなくNULLを返すんですね。(試してみて今気付きました)

なので、

```
Article.where("array_length(preload_article_ids, 1) IS NULL")
```

とNULL検査にするか、

```
Article.where("preload_article_ids = '{}' OR preload_article_ids IS NULL")
```

と空配列と比較(と必要であればNULL検査)にするか、PostgreSQL9.4以降ですが、`cardinality`関数は空配列に対して0を返すとマニュアルに書いてある(試してません)ので

```
Article.were("cardinality(preload_article_ids) = 0")
```

とこれを使うかでしょうか。